# Custom Post Types hierarchy and rewrite

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, hierarchical

I've been around this problem for 2 days, googling and experimenting with no avail.

I have this Custom Post Type name "programas", and a page with the same name.

The page "Programas" lists all the CPT "programas", and the permalink of a "programas" is /programas/name-of-cpt-post/, so far so good.

Now, each "programas" will have a detail, and the permalink should be /programas/name-of-cpt-post/detail-of-programa/. This detail is also a CPT, with the alias "detalhe-programas".

In this CPT, I choose what "programas" is the parent, so far so good.

My problem is this:

Without any change, new "detalhe-programa" permalink will be /detalhe_programas/name-of-cpt-programa-parent/detalhe-programa-post/ but I need for SEO sakes, that the structure of the link stays /programas/name-of-cpt-programa-parent/detalhe-programa-post/ (/list/parent/child)

So, on the "detalhe-programa" I've set this: 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'programas'), but with this, every page related with "programas" (list, parent, child) is 404.

Can anybody help me? I'm completly lost!

thx